# How do I add values from another table into a SQL response?

Tags: sql

I have the following tables:

games:

[image]

standings:

[image]

I am looking to build a table in the following format for each entry in the games table:

visitor_team_standing | home_team_standing | diff

I have been digging into joins to try and learn but still keep running into a problem.

```
SELECT
    standings.standing visitor_standings,
    games.diff
FROM games
INNER JOIN standings ON
    games.visitor_team_id = standings.team_id;
```

However, I can't figure out how to also include the standing for home_team (home_team_id = team-_id).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just join the standings table twice by giving each one a different alias.

```
SELECT
    visitor.standings visitor_standings,
    home.standings home_standings,
    games.diff
FROM games
INNER JOIN standings as visitor ON
    games.visitor_team_id = visitor.team_id
INNER JOIN standings as home ON
    games.home_team_id = home.team_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will set it as the correct answer as soon as the time is up.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using this code as well.

```
SELECT
   visitor.standings visitor_standings,
   home.standings home_standings,
   games.diff
FROM games
INNER JOIN standings as visitor 
ON
  games.visitor_team_id = visitor.team_id
INNER JOIN standings as Home 
ON
  games.home_team_id = home.team_id;
```

Comment: This will not work because the alias `home` is not defined